How to bundle backend(python) code along with VScode extension code
I have developed a VS code extension which has UI in typesript with nodeJS. To perform backend operation I have created APIs in python as service. Now when I have to run my extension then I have to execute my APIs using "uvicorn ExtName:app --reload" command first, then I have to run my extension. So extension calls APIs and push/pull data accordingly.
But in this scenario the biggest problem is I have to deploy services on some server which I want to avoid. I want services to be available within extension only(like we have DLLs in C#.Net project). It  should be one bundle which install in one go and on same machine  so that I can avoid server cost.
Is it possible to achieve, if yes please let me know how?
Edit:- I got to know that we can embedd python service in the VScode extension but not sure how to actually do it. If someone knows Please tell.
Thank You!!

Then what is the point of having a backend, if it's not on a server? Why isn't everything just implemented in the extension itself, since it's local anyway? If the "backend" is also just local code then there is nothing a Python "backend" could do that the extension couldn't do on its own as well, no? I don't understand the goal here.

I have to call chatgpt APIs which is not possible to call from Nodejs/ typescript so thats why I created backend with python. Please let me know if I am doing wrong and what should I have done instead of this.

The Esbonio extension does ship with some Python packages, https://github.com/swyddfa/esbonio But you will have to dig into its code base than waiting for a detailed answer.

Why would it not be possible? It's just an API. It doesn't matter what you use to call it... See the package chatgpt for instance.
